# Android: Camera Images Loaded Via Gallery Don't Show Up In ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-gallery

In short, I've got an app that I'm working on that needs to be able to take images and upload them. Before uploading them I want to show them on screen. Ideally, I should be able to load images from the phone's storage using the gallery, OR take a picture and upload it directly.

I can take a picture and show it in an ImageView without issue. I can load images from the gallery, but only those images that were downloaded from some external source seem to show up in the ImageView. For example, if I took a picture with the camera last week and wanted to choose it with the gallery, it won't load; the ImageView is just blank with no errors. This is the case for every single image I've taken with the camera; if I try to load it using the gallery it doesn't work, but if I load other images using the gallery they work. I can't figure out why this would be the case, so I'll present some relevant code here and hope someone can help me out.

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
```

And the code within onActivityResult where it's loading the image and attempting to display it:

```
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

            imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void chooseImageFromGalery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Image"), 101);
}

if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())), photoFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        refreshFragmentData();
    }
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }

}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(CommonParams.MASTER_STORAGE_PATH + "/" + CommonParams.categorySelected);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
```

And the code within onActivityResult where it's loading the image and attempting to display it:

```
              Intent imageReturnedIntent;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            File mFile = new File(filePath);
            cursor.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             options.inSampleSize = 2;
           Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
```